# C program, problem with scanning and digits

Tags: c

as a part of my program I need to scan a number with four digits, and put every digit in a different variable. Here's what I tried by now, but somehow when I run the code, it always prints 0. I can't find the problem, can someone tell me i've done wrong?

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{

    int userGuess = 0;
    int digit = 0;
    int userFourth = 0;
    int userThird = 0;
    int userSecond = 0;
    int userFirst = 0;
    printf("Write your guess\n");
    scanf("%d" , &userGuess);
    while (userGuess != 0)
    {
        int userFourth = userGuess % 10;
        userGuess = userGuess / 10;
        int userThird = userGuess % 10;
        userGuess = userGuess / 10;
        int userSecond = userGuess % 10;
        userGuess = userGuess / 10;
        int userFirst = userGuess % 10;
    }
    printf("user fourth is %d\n" , userFourth);
    printf("user third is %d\n" , userThird);
    printf("user second is %d\n" , userSecond);
    printf("user first is %d\n" , userFirst);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tip: Learn about arrays. This is not a sustainable approach to programming, and already you're developing some caustically bad habits.

Comment: The variables inside the `while` block are different than the variables outside. You're [*shadowing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) them.

Comment: It's also worth noting you can solve this with straight-up strings, there's no need for an array per-se. Remember, for a given `char x[n]` you can always refer to individual characters and test those vs. a known value, like `x[1] == '6'`.

Comment: Yet another case where one ought to pay attention to compiler warnings. This code should generate some along the lines of "variable is assigned a value but is never used".

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is *variable shadowing*, or in other words, creating two variables that are independent, but have exactly the same name:

```c
int main() {
    int userGuess = 0;
    int userFourth = 0; // Declare `userFourth`

    while (userGuess != 0)
    {
        int userFourth = userGuess % 10; // Declare another `userFourth`
```

Here there's a `userFourth` in the top level `main()` function, and *also* a `userForth` in the inner loop. They're not related. They don't share data.

Remove the `int` in the second case, don't re-declare it, just use the existing variable.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't find the problem, can someone tell me i've done wrong?

In addition to the shadowing [@tadman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65736513/2410359), line of code not needed.  No need to loop

```
// while (userGuess != 0)
```

> to scan a number with four digits, and put every digit in a different variable.

Code can directly scan  into 4 variables using a *width* limit.

Code uses `"%n"` to save the offset of the scan input to detect correct digit count.

```
int userFirst, userSecond, userThird, userFourth;

int n = 0;
scanf("%1d%1d%1d%1d%n", &userFirst, &userSecond, &userThird, &userFourth, &n);
if (n == 4) {
  puts("Success");
  printf("user fourth is %d\n" , userFourth);
  printf("user third is %d\n" , userThird);
  printf("user second is %d\n" , userSecond);
  printf("user first is %d\n" , userFirst);
} else {
  puts("Fail");
}
```